# Showing a loading image before an image is loaded with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-load, jquery-on

I've followed a few different similar questions here on SO but it's not working for some reason. Can someone help me understand why? I want the loading image to show first, then fade out when the bigger image is loaded. The bigger image should fade in.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95rpu029/2/

**HTML**

```
<article class="project">
    <img width="375" height="375" src="http://dummyimage.com/375x375/000/fff" class="attachment-home-thumb">
</article>
```

**JS**

```
// Show loading image
$('article').prepend('<span class="loading-icon"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/lJpvTU3.gif" height="32" width="32" alt="Loading..."></span>');

// main image loaded ?
$('article img').on('load', function(){
    // hide/remove the loading image
    $('.loading-icon').fadeOut();
    $('article').show();
});
```

**CSS**

```
article.project {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 2%;
    max-width: 375px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 23%;
}

article.project img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: seems you have done that, what is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your test image is quite small and it is already loaded before your code gets a chance to run. So `load` is not fired (as image already loaded). I have made small change to your code and updated the <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95rpu029/9/)</kbd>. The changes are as follows:

1. show loader image at start
2. create an `Image` object and wire `onload` of this object
3. assign it source (the actual image that you want to load)
4. when event occurs, assign source to original image

   ```
   var im = new Image();
   im.onload = function () {
       $("#img2Replace")[0].src = im.src;
   };
   im.src = "http://dummyimage.com/375x375/000/fff";
   ```

Well now we have to do this for each image:

```
    var imgs = $("article.project img.attachment-home-thumb");
    $.each(imgs, function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var im = new Image();
        im.onload = function () {
            var theImage = $this;
            $this.hide("slow");
            theImage[0].src = im.src;
            $this.show('fast');
        };
        im.src = $this.data("mainsrc");
    });
```

Note that to simulate delay in loading actual image, I have used `setTimeout` in fiddle.

Comment: Is there something that would prevent a group of these images being loaded together? It works fine with one image, but with a grid of images, only the first one gets the image src changed once loaded.

Comment: do all images have same source?

Comment: No, they don't. But even when I tried putting in the same source (http://dummyimage.com/375x375/000/fff) to test, only the first one loaded. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95rpu029/8/

Comment: I have updated the filddle to handle multiple images

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how can I make each loading image fade out and having the actual image fade directly in its place? Right now it seems to be fading out, then all of the boxes shrink, then the actual images fade in.